# Derivation of equation for period of cantilever beam when the distance between the point at which a mass is attached and the pivot changes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, structural-beam

I am a high school student writing a research paper on cantilever beams. I am investigating the relationship between the distance at which a fixed mass is placed on the beam and the time period of its oscillation. On a 100cm ruler, I made holes at regular intervals. Each time, I attached a (100g)mass to one of the holes and gave it an initial displacement, causing an oscillation.

I found a similar ([question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717939/deriving-an-equation-for-the-shm-of-a-cantilever-beam-with-a-mass-attached-at-th)) that was asked on physics stackexchange before. However, my experiment is different.

I would like to investigate how the distance between the pivot and the added mass affects the period of the ruler. I tried a lot to derive an equation for this experiment but failed to do so. Please help me with the derivation of a formula for this experiment. If in your opinion, this experiment is way too complicated for high school physics, please suggest a better IV and DV using the same set-up.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150957/discussion-on-question-by-aaditya-derivation-of-equation-for-period-of-cantileve); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mass of the beam is negligible w.r.t. the other mass, it's possible to build a model with only one degree of freedom, resulting in a simple harmonic oscillator.

It's possible to split the dynamical system in 2 subsystems: the beam, and the mass; these subsystems are connected by force condition ($3^{rd}$ principle of dynamics) and by the kinematic condition (the displacement of the mass is the same as the displacement of the beam tip).

**Beam.** If the mass of the beam is negligible, the beam has static response. If it's so, we can build a mathematical model and evaluating the stiffness of the beam using only principles and tools that you could already know at the high school: equilibrium and ordinary derivatives and integrals of powers.

Equilibrium provides the link between the tip force $F$ exchanged with the mass and the internal bending moment in the beam $M(x) = - F(\ell - x)$.
Bernoulli-Euler beam model links the bending moment to the second order derivative of the transverse displacement of the beam $w(x)$,
\begin{equation}
  M(x) = EJ w''(x) \ ,
\end{equation}
through the bending stiffness as the combination of the elastic modulus of the material $E$ and the inertial of the section $J$.

Performing the integration, as shown below, we can link the displacement of the free end of the beam $w(\ell)$ to the force $F$,
\begin{equation}
  F = - \frac{EJ}{3 \ell^3} w(\ell)
\end{equation}

**Mass.** The dynamic of the mass is governed by the $2^{nd}$ principle of Newton's mechanics
\begin{equation}
  M \ddot{x} = F \ ,
\end{equation}
and using the expression of $F$ already from the beam, and recalling that $w(\ell) = x$, we get the equation of a harmonic oscillator,
\begin{equation}
  M \ddot{w} + \frac{EJ}{3 \ell^3} w = 0 \ ,
\end{equation}
with pulsation
\begin{equation}
  \Omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{K}{M}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{3EJ}{M \ell^3}}
\end{equation}
and period
\begin{equation}
  T = \frac{2\pi}{\Omega} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\dfrac{M \ell^3}{3 EJ}} \ .
\end{equation}

Being $J = \frac{1}{12} b h^3$ (see below) for a beam with rectangular section, we get the expression for the period
\begin{equation}
  T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\dfrac{4 M \ell^3}{E b h^3}} \ .
\end{equation}

[image]

The moment of inertia $J$ of a beam reads
\begin{equation}
  J = \int_A y^2 dA \ ,
\end{equation}
and for a rectangular section,
\begin{equation}
  J = \int_A y^2 dA = \int_{x=-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}} \int_{y=-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} y^2 dx dy = \frac{1}{12} \ .
\end{equation}
[image]

Comment: hi @basics I finally got the time to work on this experiment, I went through your model but I am struggling to understand most of it:(  Can you help me a bit please. I am wondering if it is possible to come up with a model that just gives an equation for the effective mass of the beam whcih I can substitute into the existing equation.